# How to write to a text file upon creation?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, terminal

I'm self-learning command line code and can't seem to find an answer.

I'm using the standard MacOS Terminal application to create directories/files for practice.

my question is, can I use a code to include what would get written to the file as I create it?

I've tried:

```
touch one/texttest.txt echo "Hello"
```

But this only creates 3 files, one called hello, one called echo, and a third called texttest.txt within the "one" folder

I've also tried these and got the same results:

```
touch echo "Hello" ~/one/texttest.txt

echo Hello ~/one/texttest.txt

touch one/texttest.txt Hello
```

I can't seem to find any solutions for the standard terminal app with 0 plugins, is this even possible?

Comment: The purpose of the [`touch`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?touch) command is to update a file's modified timestamp; it just happens to also create the file if it doesn't exist. It's not the only way (or even the usual way) to create a new file in the shell, however. Danny's solution below shows a common way, which is the redirect the output of a command (`echo` in this case) to a file using the [`>` redirection operator](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_lts0070.php).

Comment: I see that, does the file have to exist before I redirect to it, or can I use the redirection operate '>' on a file that doesn't exist and it makes it for me?
EDIT: just answered my own question, thanks!

Comment: It will create a file if it doesn't exist. Here's a great overview of IO redirection and the other operators that are available: http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_lts0070.php

Comment: Not sure I'd call that "a great overview" but it certainly is a gently introduction to some of the basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
echo "Hello" > one/texttest.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept your answer in 5mins, when the timer is done.

Answer (score 1):

```
touch one/texttest.txt echo "Hello"
```

That is the `touch` command with three arguments: `one/texttest.txt`, `echo`, and `Hello` (the shell removes the quotes).

```
touch echo "Hello" ~/one/texttest.txt
touch one/texttest.txt Hello
```

These are the same as the first one (different arguments but same concept).

```
echo Hello ~/one/texttest.txt
```

This is the `echo` command with two arguments: `Hello`, and `~/one/texttest.txt` (only the `~` will have been expanded to your home directory by the time `echo` sees it).

`touch` only creates files (and updates timestamps) it doesn't write content.

You could have a `touch` command that takes content also but I don't know of one.

Luckily you don't need one because the shell can do this for you.

You use `echo Hello` to run `echo` and have it spit out `Hello` and you tell the shell to "redirect" the text to a file instead of the screen.

```
echo Hello > texttest.txt
```

It is worth pointing out that redirection creates the file whether you write anything to it or not (and in fact whether the command works or even exists or even if a command is given).

```
$ ls /tmp/texttest.txt
ls: /tmp/texttest.txt: No such file or directory
$ flekjfe Hello > /tmp/texttest.txt
$ ls /tmp/texttest.txt
/tmp/texttest.txt
```

So you can use `> file` all by itself to create a new empty file for example.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of what my commands were actually doing, coming from a background of front-end design, this is all really new and different to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use output redirection command_output > file

For more details : http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html